# Custom MenuItem Control Template

Tags: wpf, menuitem, controltemplate

I have generated a custom control template for menu items. I modified the IsChecked trigger to change the appearance of the menu item in IsChecked state so that the glyphPanel is hidden and the menu item has a light blue background. But what I haven't achieved yet is to limit the Background fill to the icon, like it was in Windows forms. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Visible"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg">
      <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
          <GradientStop Color="#34C5EBFF" Offset="0"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#3481D8FF" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Trigger>
  ...
```

Comment: Couldn't you just put a border around your icon image control and change the background on that instead of changing the background on the entire control?

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your reply. Good idea, that helped me!